# Batch processing las files with LASzip from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, lidar, qgis-processing, lastools, laz

I am using QGIS 2.16 version. I added LAStools plugin and executed batch process, in a way that I have to write each filename in the output field. Is there any automatic process to get outputs with the same original name separately?

Also, I'm having to select each file one by one to provide the input file. How to provide multiple inputs if several .las files are available?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. This is not a very clear question. Please take the [tour] to learn how to ask a focused question.

Answer (score 1):

Check this tutorial on [Batch Processing using Processing Framework](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/batch_processing.html).

For loading multiple files, the key is

> 12. In the Batch Processing dialog, the first tab is Parameters where we define out inputs. Click the ... next to the first row in the Input layer column.
> 13. Browse to the directory containing the global transportation layers that you had downloaded. Hold the Ctrl key and select all the layers that you want to clip. You may also use Shift or Ctrl-A to make multiple selection. Click Open.

For output it's

> 15. Browse the the directory where you want your output layers. Type the filename as clipped_ and click Save.
> 16. You will see a new Autofill settings dialog pop up. Select Fill with parameter values as the Autofill mode. Select Parameter to use as Input layer. This setting will add the input file name to the output along with the specified output_ filename. This is important to ensure all the output files have unique names and they do not overwrite each other.

Comment: Thank you so much for your information........but its not possible to select more than one file in laszip tool in Las tool plugin